# What is Renaissance Humanism?

Tags: renaissance, philosophy

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of Renaissance humanism. I've been reading about it for some time and I've found definitions, or explanations, varying in focus from it being a revival of classical antiquity (which was basically what the Renaissance was) to its emphasis on the potential of man. I don't even understand if it was a method of learning or a philosophy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: What is wrong with the definition in [Wikipedia:Humanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism)?   or Dictionary, "an outlook or system of thought attaching prime importance to human rather than divine or supernatural matters." Professor Thomas Noble  [In the Foundations of Western Civ](https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Foundations-of-Western-Civilization-Audiobook/B00DIATCXA?qid=1633367294&sr=1-1&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_1&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=JRA8H18AYK1R38B23XXH) covers the ambiguity. It isn't simple.

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of Humanism is essentially a belief that there is an inherent goodness in being human. It puts a lot of emphasis on solving problems rationally (which humans are quite good at) and the idea that humans are “naturally good”. What makes Renaissance humanism so important is that at the time, the church ran most of educational facilities and therefore art and literature became ‘churchified’. Statues were very stagnant and literature was not very thought provoking aside from the theological aspects, and even that was limited to the elites that could read and write.

As I’m sure you’re aware, the renaissance changed that drastically. We see a MASSIVE shift in the way art is made, artist put more effort into including the dynamics of the human body (see Michael Angelos statue of David). In comparison the church was not focused on the human qualities of their statues but their representation of heavenliness. They did not want the physique to distract from God. We see this in several other works as well. Most books published at the time before the renaissance were largely bibles and analysis of it. However we begin to see an analysis of the human condition as opposed to God. For example Machiavelli gave published his works on political science and Dante’s Inferno describes hell through a human perspective (vs that of what God tells us)

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.